# How to extract only the required fields from an OpenAPI schema?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swaggerhub

I have an OpenAPI definition in JSON format that I have uploaded to SwaggerHub. The OpenAPI definition has one API method that has a substantial payload. Is it possible, via SwaggerHub or some other tool, to only extract the required fields so I can see what a minimal payload looks like?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Contract testing, response mocking, something else?

Comment: Contract testing